# AngularFire Priority changes not working, inserting duplicate items instead

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an angularFireCollection on list with priorities. I see extremely odd behavior. Basically when a priority changes, let's say item #2 becomes #1, instead of moving the item it just overwrites #1 as #2 and there's now a duplicate of the item with the former #1 simply disappearing.

How do I fix this?

```
$scope.docs = angularFireCollection(fb.child('view/docs').limit(20).startAt());
```

This is the line of code that controls the display of list. I'm not sure what else to share that would be relevant.

Comment: That doesn't sound like standard behavior. Can you share your code?

Comment: @Kato I added a bit of sample code, please let me know if it's not enough.

Comment: Priorities aren't fully supported in angularFire yet, [see this bug](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/19). However, I still couldn't create a duplicate entry by changing a priority, [see this fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/vVk6E/6/). I'm not sure why you're worried about posting too much code, the more the merrier, and at the very least, we need enough code to reproduce the issue (it needs to run)

Comment: I recreated the issue with duplicates and added it to the existing bug. I think the only workaround for the time being may be to use angularFire instead of angularFireCollection, which will at least ensure proper ordering.

Comment: @Kato so angularFire doesn't work with priorities at all and aFireCollection has the duplicates bug? No solution at all?

Comment: Sorry, I don't gather. angularFire uses on('value'), which means it's getting the entire object from the db. It can't help but be in the correct order.

Comment: @Kato AngularFire doesn't order correctly, doesn't even work with angular's orderBy. It's weird.

Comment: @Kato I tested manually and Firebase's on 'value' does not return in the priority order. What a joke? child_added and pushing manually does return in priority order though.

Comment: @Harry, you can use snapshot.forEach() in the 'value' callback to iterate through the items in priority order. We also just pushed a fix to the angularFireCollection priority code, you can fetch the latest from Github.

Comment: I'm also seeing this in my own code, but I'm trying to produce a limited test case to rule out reference issues on my end. I'm using an ng-repeat against an angularFireCollection and updating the priority of individual items to sort them to the top, and I'm seeing the old items get overwritten. Is the collection fix in 0.3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is fixed in the latest angularfire.